# Making Gvim work with Powershell

Tags: powershell, vim, vi

In gvim when I want to execute something like,`:!ls` it send this command to the regular Command prompt `cmd.exe`. So, I can't use `ls` or `pwd` or any of the regular linux commands. But, PowerShell supports most of the Linux type commands. So, how can I set PowerShell as the default shell for vim?

Answer (score 7):

Set the vim `shell` variable to the PowerShell executable:

```
set shell=C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
```